# Migrating CiviCrm to WordPress CMS from Drupal

Tags: wordpress, civievent, civimail, drupal, contacts

The wiki guide doesn't work. I ran into issues concerning moving the civi contacts...ie Drupal users. This is obviously very very crucially needed. I have over 5000 thus I cannot move forward. I was told to write a new question. So here it is. If anyone has tried this and had it fail... Please help

Update: Being that this is complicated and likely several glitches will arise after trying this again... I've opted never to do this. It's too risky and I'll lose historical information back to 2012. I'm unwilling. Seems not many successfully do this or is see much more on Stack exchange

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. As with any kind of troubleshooting, we cannot really help you without details. Which wiki? At which step? Did you already import your Drupal users to WordPress? What versions of all the various platforms are you working with, and in what environment? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Your commentary doesn't help and the versions aren't relevant to give advice. I'd give those things if you'd given me some  kind of suggestion like below

Comment: My commentary is designed to help you improve the question, which is why I made it as a comment and not an answer. StackExchange is not a discussion forum; the answers are supposed to be definitive and well-referenced, but the questions likewise are supposed to be clear and well-researched.

Comment: You see there is an answer someone wrote. You trying to belittle my question is rather inappropriate and talking about my post like I'm a child. One wonders why you are a moderator when you obviously have little else to do other than tell people their questions aren't good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Export a csv list from Drupal or phpmyadmin? Then import it into WordPress via a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv/ You can disable/delete the plugin after you are done. You will also want to use the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/ to create/sync the users in Civi.

Comment: I want to others to give feedback. I've not implemented this yet and want to see if there might be other wrinkles in this process which I didn't see. Thanks again.

Comment: It didn't work and I've not tried to do this in production

Comment: Also there are no instructions on getting CSV import out of Drupal...I couldn't find this functionality anywhere and Drupal is very complicated. I tried one method but the file would not go into WordPress via plugin. Therefore I'm giving up. This is just too risky and complex

Comment: To anyone else that is researching this same question looking for answers... This solution will work if you have a csv file.

Comment: You did not explain how to create one or how exports work in Drupal so the question is not answered

Comment: You young man are a real piece of work!!!   StackExchange is designed to give a helping hand to those that are making an effort.  Look at the subdomain above, Do you see Drupal or WordPress there? NO IT SAYS CIVICRM!!!!!            I recommend you hire some help. StackExchange is not designed for people with your level of experience or drive to try. Here is a list of experienced CiviCRM experts https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Comment: But if you insist on doing this yourself, The internet is full of these wonderful sites called "Search Engines". In case you have yet to have heard of them, here is a link to Wiki's description of them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_search_engine  To be even more helpful, most people use the one called Google https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpoMoeGbzuM  But bottomline, when you need to do something simple like "How to cook pasta" or "Export User List from Drupal", you can type your questions in and get INSTANT answers. WaLa!!

Comment: I recommend you STFU!  I can type whatever I like on MY question and CIVI runs on a few platforms and saying things that are platform specific are important to add!  So how about you keep your condescending comments to yourself and kindly take a long walk off a short pier!  #Moron I obviously have googled a lot of info.  How about you crawl back into your IOWA hole pal.  I was not talking to you.  I was addressing the guy above.